# str_replace not replacing my h2 tag when using dom outerhtml

Tags: php, parsing, dom, str-replace

I have this code below that is parsing the html using dom

The parsing is working but I can't make the str_replace get to work.

when I var_dump both $old_h2 and $new_h2 the output is correct but the string length is incorrect could this be a factor why the variable is not being passed?

when I echo the content nothing is being changed.

Im not sure how can I debug this.

Is there a way to know if the variable is being passed to the str_replace?

```
<?php
$editorStr = strtr(get_sub_field('editor') , $arr);
if (get_row_layout() == 'condensed title_&_description')
{
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($editorStr, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'));
    $dom->encoding = 'utf-8';

    $h2tags = $dom->getElementsByTagName('h2');

    if ($h2tags->length > 0)
    {
        $title = $h2tags->item(0)->textContent;
    }               
    
    for($i=0;$i<=$dom->getElementsByTagName("h2")->length;$i++)
    {
        $h2 = $dom->getElementsByTagName("h2")->item($i);
        $old_h2 = outerHTML($h2);
        
        $h2->setAttribute('class', 'content-title');
        $h2->setAttribute('data-title', 'title-' . ($counter + 1));

        $new_h2 = outerHTML($h2);           
        
        $newacfcontent  = str_replace( $old_h2,$new_h2,$editorStr);
        echo $newacfcontent;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: There's probably differences in whitespace, which aren't easily seen when you dump the variables in an HTML page. Try doing the `var_dump()` inside `<pre>` elements.

Comment: Why are you using string functions for this? The changes to the DOM elements in `$h2` should be all you need to do. At the end just use `$dom->saveXHTML()` to get all the modified elements.